# arithmetic operation differs if variable is char or int

Tags: c

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char y=3, res=0;
    res = ( (++y) * (++y) );
    printf("res=%d    y=%d \n", res, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
res=20    y=5
```

Now when i change variable to `int` it gives different results

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int y=3, res=0;
    res = ( (++y) * (++y) );
    printf("res=%d    y=%d \n", res, y);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
res=25    y=5
```

What happened to make `res` value change?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour - anything goes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/168175, haven't earned a dupe hammer for C so will leave to someone else

Comment: @Nasr Please use search next time before asking.

Comment: Did you really put any effort in searching about the solution ?

Comment: @2501 i tried to search but it wasn't clear to me what should i search for

Comment: @Nasr It is ok if you try and fail.

Comment: "_Please use search next time before asking_" -- Good advice, but frankly, searching "char++ vs int++" will not give any answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing there is undefined behavior. If it were defined (either by the spec or by the implemetation), you'd get the same result no matter what data type you used. The value will also change due to optimization.